# Play second ending in "The World Next Door" without replaying the whole game?

Tags: the-world-next-door

“The World Next Door” has a couple of places, where you can get somewhat different information based on who you priorize interacting with. But the big distinction is in the ending, where a binary choice is given.

Sadly, the game autosaves after the last dungeon, right before the final scene, and it doesn't have a savegame system other than “continue from autosave”. As a consequence, there is no obvious way to replay the last dungeon with the second option.

Now, I really liked the game and would like to see both endings. But I didn't like it enough to play it all over again, just for that.

Is there any possibility to play the second ending *without* starting the game over?

Answer (score 1):

From the relevant [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/ehkyuc/play_second_ending_in_the_world_next_door_without/):

- For the PC version it is possible, but only by backing up the savegame before making the decision. (They should be stored inside the installation directory.)
- Switch players are probably out of luck.
- The next best thing I found is [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYY8WEwezto).